# array of arrays in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to define a array of arrays. 
I have defined:

```
  integer,dimension(2,2):: & 
    x=reshape(source= (/0,1,1,0/),  shape=(/2,2/)), & 
    y=reshape(source= (/1,0,0,1/),  shape=(/2,2/)), & 
    z=reshape(source= (/1,1,1,1/),  shape=(/2,2/))
```

I want to define an array, say, s(3),  of which, (x/y/z) are components, i.e.

```
s(1)=x 
s(2)=y 
and s(3)=z
```

how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest approach might be to define `s` as a rank-3 array, perhaps

```
integer, dimension(3,2,2) :: s
```

and then you can write statements such as

```
s(1,:,:) = x
s(2,:,:) = y
...
```

This is the 'natural' way to implement an array of arrays in Fortran.  An alternative, which might appeal to you more would be something like:

```
type :: twodarray
   integer, dimension(2,2) :: elements
end type twodarray

type(twodarray), dimension(3) :: s

s(1)%elements = x
```

If you don't like the wordiness of `s(1)%elements = x` you could redefine the operation `=` for your type `twodarray`, I don't have time right now to write that code for you.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use pointers (in Fortran 95)

```
program main
  implicit none

  type :: my_type
     integer, pointer :: my_size(:)      ! F95
     !integer, allocatable :: my_size(:) ! F95 + TR 15581 or F2003
  end type my_type

  type(my_type), allocatable :: x(:)

  allocate(x(3))

  allocate(x(1)%my_size(3))
  allocate(x(2)%my_size(2))
  allocate(x(3)%my_size(1))

  print*, x(1)%my_size
  print*, x(2)%my_size
  print*, x(3)%my_size

  deallocate(x(3)%my_size, x(2)%my_size, x(1)%my_size)
  deallocate(x)

end program main
```

It will print

```
       0           0           0
       0           0
       0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a complete program that uses “(re-)allocation on assignment”, which makes dynamic arrays be more like variables in a dynamically typed language.

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer,dimension(2,2):: & 
    x=reshape(source= (/0,1,1,0/),  shape=(/2,2/)), & 
    y=reshape(source= (/1,0,0,1/),  shape=(/2,2/)), & 
    z=reshape(source= (/1,1,1,1/),  shape=(/2,2/))

  type :: my_type
     integer, allocatable :: component(:,:)
  end type my_type

  type(my_type) :: s(3)

  s(1)%component=x
  s(2)%component=y
  s(3)%component=z

  print*, s(1)%component
  print*, s(2)%component
  print*, s(3)%component
end program main
```

It outputs:

```
           0           1           1           0
           1           0           0           1
           1           1           1           1
```